# Large gap at bottom of webpage

Tags: css, xhtml

What usually causes a large gap in excessive whitesapce on webpage like this one:

http://beta.globerunnerseo.com/contact/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#sidebar-sm #blog span, #sidebar-sm #facebook span, #sidebar-sm #twitter span, #sidebar-sm #linkedin span, #sidebar-sm #quote span {
left:-999em;
position:absolute;
top:999em;
}
```

It's the top:999em. I think you were supposed to specify negative for the top, not positive ( eg `top:-9999px` or `top:-999em` )

Even if validating doesn't resolve the issue you should strive to make your page valid before asking to save time.

Answer (score 3):

First, your page doesn't validate: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbeta.globerunnerseo.com%2Fcontact%2F

Second, you have a CSS rule for the html tag at `height: 100%`. I assume this is to position the footer at the bottom of the page. Do you have any large backgrounds set for your top level elements?

I think the combination of the two may be throwing you off, but probably just the first one. This amount of space is definitely *wrong*.

Get your page to validate, then comment back.